# Concurrent reading/editing of file

Tags: .net, concurrency, io

I have a flat file database (an xml file). I have a client that reads and edits this database. I have the xml file in one directory which many clients connect to. If one client makes an edit, it needs to update on all the clients.

I can't use a database and must use this flat file structure (ie I can't have a managing server application running all the time)

The clients are running XP and .NET

What are the modern solutions to this issue? I haven't done any XP or .NET coding in a while, would it be easy to simply use file locks? Do you even have separate read/write locks on XP?

**EDIT**

The clients are all on seperate machines and the database is stored on a network share.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [System.Threading.Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) to handle reading/editing accesses to this file. In your class in which you are manipulating this flat file or reading it, you should write

```
yourMutex.WaitOne();
ReaderOrWrite();
yourMutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

you can find a good sample code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c41ybyt3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in which it also handles the situation when no mutex has been created.

Mutex is a kind of Semaphore used to handle multi accesses to critical areas, in your example the xml file, and provide a solution to preventing concurrent execution of the critical section.

Comment: I apologise, I feel I didn't give enough information. Please see my edit in the OP. I don't think Mutexs would work here as they are only persistant on one machine? (That was my impression anyways)

Comment: So one easy way that crosses my mind is to write a web service on the machine that hosts the xml file and let this service handle the access to the file by using mutex or any other approach that is convenient for you.

Comment: Can't do that - don't have access to any machines that are running 24/7.

Comment: What do you mean by not having access to the machines? You can't edit your application code and update it on machines? As long as I know the common and robust way to implement such feature, is using .net remoting or socket programming or through web services technologies